# How can I set this div's width to be screen-wide?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make .container (the div with yellow border) take the full width of its parent (body), that is screen width, I don't know what makes it narrow and centered like that

```
.container {
background: url("https://image.ibb.co/e7L09w/rsz_pexels_photo_540518.png") no-repeat fixed center bottom;
background-size: cover;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 120px 1fr 150px;
border: 2px solid yellow;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

See pen below :

https://codepen.io/mrassili/pen/wPxpgL

Comment: use container-fluid instead ... this is bootstrap. container has a max-width

Comment: Yeah that's right thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

As @Temani Afif said, you are using Bootstrap, and therefore the class `.container` will give the div a max-width.
Use the class `container-fluid` instead, it has no max-width, thus the width will be screen-sized.